# Is there a way to implement webrtc server for one to many server with node JS?

Tags: webrtc, one-to-many

I am trying to implement a live streaming application using flutter. For that, I need to implement a webRTC server with NodeJS. Is there a way to implement a webrtc server for one to many server with node JS?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Mediasoup](https://github.com/versatica/mediasoup). It's a WebRTC server implemented in NodeJS. You can install it just like any npm package and use along with rest of your implementation.